# How to use GREP to only style a part of the expression?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I like to use GREP in In-Design, the problem is I have a menu like so:

`HAMBURGER Johnny's Favorite    3.50`

I like `Johnny's Favorite` to be styled differently.
The first part, the dish, may contain separate words like: `SPICEY CHICKEN`. However the dish is always written in capitals.

So I thought:`[^a-z]+ [A-Z][^A-Z]+ Favorite`.

Only now the dish is styled too. I am only interested in the favorite part, but it must begin with dish to validate. So I thought maybe I had to group it like so: `[^a-z]+ ([A-Z][^A-Z]+ Favorite)`. But that didn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have `[^a-z]+` as part of your search query, so that will be a part of what it finds and applies any changes to, regardless of whether you group it or not. You could use a lookbehind, but a lookbehind must have a calculable length, so you can’t use `+` in it. You could do something like `(?<=\u{3}\s)\u\l+ Favorite`, if you’re certain there will always be at least three uppercase letters at the end. Or you could add something unique after the dish name and use nested styles instead.

Comment: One of the best ways to match stuff is mathcing for what i dont want in a lookbehind or lookahead

Comment: I am trying it right now. I will let you know.

Comment: Why don't use use TAB separators between the parts of your text lines, because in the end you will likely want to vertically align individual parts for better readability. Right? RegEx will become much simpler afterwards too.

Answer (score 3):

This should work in your case:

`(?<=\u )\u[^\u\s].*Favorite`

or the more general:

`(?<=\u )\u[^\u\s].*\l`

#### Explanation

`(?<=\u )` - first we search for any uppercase character followed by a space (the end of an uppercase word), wrapped in a *positive lookbehind* so we don't include the match

`\u` - followed by any uppercase character

`[^\u\s]` - followed by any non-uppercase and non-whitespace character (this makes sure to include any apostrophes right after the first letter like in `D'Angelo's`)

`.*` - followed by zero or more characters of any kind

`Favorite` - followed by the word `Favorite` (assuming the text you want to select always ends with that word)

or:

`\l` followed by a lowercase character (assuming the text you want to select always ends with a lowercase letter and never with an apostrophe or other punctuation)

#### Usage

Works both with *GREP Styles*:

[image]

and with *Find/Change*:

[image]

Comment: This is better than MG_’s answer, but it still misses the requisite of also checking that an all-caps dish name precedes the string to match, so it will match “HAMBURGER Johnny’s Favorite”, but also just “Johnny’s Favorite”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I don't understand. Are you referring to the "it must begin with dish to validate" part? I'm not sure I understand that sentence 100%. Do you really think that there are lines with no dish names in all caps which mustn't be matched?

Comment: Yeah, that’s the one. It’s not super-clearly worded, but I figure there are probably be lines that don’t have any dish name at all, so the special formatting isn’t wanted there, because that’s specifically for the post-dish-name description bit.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, is it better now?

Comment: Yeah, that’s about as good as I’ve been able to get it too – perhaps `(?<=\u{2} )`, just to avoid lines that start with “A Something…”, but otherwise I think that’s as good as it’s going to get.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, ungh you're right. I can't remember now why I chose not to do that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, ah! What if there is a `HAMBURGER I` and `HAMBURGER II`? Or even a `HAMBURGER 3`. The OP must customize this to make it fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Given your very specific requirements, this pattern will work:

```
\b[A-Z][^A-Z]+ \b
```

Example: [regexr.com/5t8lj](https://regexr.com/5t8lj)

[image]

Comment: This seems to work if you use it in a *GREP Style*, but not if you perform a *Find/Change*. Besides that it includes the "trailing" spaces, so if the applied styling has something like underline or *Paragraph Shading*, it won't work.

Comment: Also this misses the caveat “but it must begin with dish to validate” – this will also match a similar string that isn’t preceded by an all-caps dish name.

Comment: Yep, I missed part of the brief. Wolff's got it.